# #ClearCase rename a VOB which is private mode in Windows

Tags: rename, clearcase

I wanted to rename a VOB which is in private mode in Base Clearcase (Windows platform)> can anyone tell me the steps.

Comment: What have you done already?

Answer (score 1):

While [`cleartool mktag -replace`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_mktag.htm) can change the tag indeed, this is not the official rename procedure recommended.

Even for [private vob](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21128196) (ie a vob which can only be activated by its owner), the rename process should follow the "[IBM Renaming a ClearCase VOB or View](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21124390).

It requires that both the storage and the tag be renamed.

```
cleartool umount \<VOB-tag>
cleartool rmtag -vob -all \<VOB-tag>
cleartool unregister -vob <VOB-storage-pname>.vbs
  # Unix
  mv <old-VOB-storage> <new-VOB-storage>.vbs 
  # Windows
  rename <old-VOB-storage> <new-VOB-storage>.vbs
cleartool register -vob <new-VOB-storage>.vbs
cleartool mktag -vob -public -tag \<new-VOB-tag> <new-VOB-storage>.vbs
cleartool mount <new-VOB-tag>
```

Answer (score -2):

Pretty straightforward.

```
cleartool mktag -replace \newname \\server\share\path\to\vbs
```